# typeof() breaks up before condition starts

Tags: javascript

I've a question... I'm trying to write a fallback for a requested json object:

```
if( typeof(json.locationData.google.results[1].formatted_address) === 'undefined' ) {
console.log('is undefined');
} else {
console.log('is not undefined', json.locationData.google.results[1].formatted_address);
}
```

**RESULT:**
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatted_address' of undefined(…)
@line of "typeof(json.locationData.google.results[1].formatted_address) === 'undefined'"

Of course it's undefined, but in this case I want the console output "yeah, it is fkn undefined"!

Any suggestions? - Thanks

Comment: You need to check whether `.results[1]` exists **before** you are trying to access `.formatted_address`.

Comment: `typeof` does not need `()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read error message carefully: `Cannot read property`**`'formatted_address'`**`of undefined`. This means that object which has property `formatted_address` is undefined. So in your code you need to check that first:

```
if( typeof(json.locationData.google.results[1]) === 'undefined' ||
    typeof(json.locationData.google.results[1].formatted_address) === 'undefined' ) {
   // ...
}
```

Or instead for checking that `typeof` is undefined, you could invert if and check for truthy value:

```
if(json.locationData.google.results[1] && json.locationData.google.results[1].formatted_address) {
   // this code block is executed when results[1] and formatted_address
   // both have a truthy value
} else {
   // if either results[1] or formatted_address are undefined 
   // then this code block is executed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the initial object exists then you can pass each property or an empty object ({}) until the final property is hit.

The {} only gets used when a property is falsy, such as null or undefined. This syntax is pretty quick to type as you go.

A few ways to do this:
    // the main object must exist
    if ( typeof json == 'undefined' ) {
        var json = {};
    }

```
var exists = ((((json.locationData||{}).google||{}).results||{})[1]||{}).formatted_address;

//then 
console.log(exists ? ('is not undefined', json.locationData.google.results[1].formatted_address) : 'is undefined');

// or
exists && console.log('is not undefined', json.locationData.google.results[1].formatted_address);
!exists && console.log('is undefined');

// or
exists ? console.log('is not undefined', json.locationData.google.results[1].formatted_address) : console.log('is undefined');
```